# Logout popup not working. How can I make one in MSAL

Tags: javascript, azure, vuejs2

I am working on a project and trying to find out how to make a **logout button** on my webpage. It is using `Vue2` and my script looks like this right now.

```js
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "Blank for security", // THIS SHGULD BE COMING FROM AN ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE VIA vue-cli dotenv
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/",
  },
};

const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      msalInstance,
      isLoggedIn: false,
      loginError: false,
      drawer: null,
    }),
    methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup({
          redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/",
        });

        console.log(loginResponse.account.username);

        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.loginError = error;
      }
    },
  },
  }
```

i've looked for information about making a logout, but mainly they are all login, and i searched here, and cant seem to find how to log them out.

this is all using `msar-browser`. It might be something simple but i'm not 100% sure, on how to use it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The MSAL library for JavaScript enables client-side JavaScript applications to authenticate users using Azure Active Directory accounts (AAD), Microsoft personal accounts (MSA) and social identity providers like Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, and Microsoft accounts through Azure AD B2C service.

Coming back to your problem, the logout process for MSAL takes two steps.

1. Clear the MSAL cache.
2. Clear the session on the identity server.

The `PublicClientApplication` object exposes APIs that perform these actions.

You can solve your problem by using **logoutRedirect**. Using `logoutRedirect` will clear the local cache of user tokens and then redirect the window to the server signout page, as shown below.

```js
const currentAccount = msalInstance.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId);
await msalInstance.logoutRedirect({
        account: currentAccount,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "https:/***/loggedOutPage"
    });
```

I would suggest reading this [Logging Out of MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md) document on GitHub to get an understanding of the same.

Also, check the well-defined example in this [**Vue.js User Authentication**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/vue-js-user-authentication/#implement-authentication-with-msal-js-2-0) document for more information.

Comment: Ok thank you, I found a `.logout` but it was deprecated. Thank you for the help! :D

Comment: also `homeAccountId` what is there? I dont have that variable nor do i know how to get there home account ID.

Comment: @monke you can get homeAccountID from your active account which is usually accounts[0]